# Evaluating a limit $\lim_{n\to0} n(\ln{n})^{p}$

Tags: limits

How to find this limit by comparison:

$$\lim_{n\to0} n(\ln{n})^{p}$$ for $p>0$.

Can anyone give me a hint

Comment: Perhaps write $n = e^{-t}$ and let $t\to\infty$?

Comment: For small $n$, $n(\ln n)^p\leq n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ln(n) = -t$, i.e., $n=e^{-t}$. We then have that if $n \to 0$, then $t \to \infty$. Hence,
$$\lim_{n \to 0} n (\ln(n))^p = \lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-t} (-t)^p = (-1)^p\lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{t^p}{e^t}$$
Note that
$$e^t = 1 + t + \dfrac{t^2}{2!} + \dfrac{t^3}{3!} + \cdots + \dfrac{t^p}{p!} + \dfrac{t^{p+1}}{(p+1)!} + \cdots > \dfrac{t^{p+1}}{(p+1)!}$$
Hence,
$$0 < \dfrac{t^p}{e^t} < (p+1)!\dfrac{t^p}{t^{p+1}} = \dfrac{(p+1)!}{t}\implies 0 < \lim_{t \to \infty}\dfrac{t^p}{e^t} < \lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{(p+1)!}t = 0$$